# How do I make pagespeed follow htaccess directives?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-pagespeed

According to the manual, you can manipulate how mod-pagespeed works using .htaccess files:
https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/module/configuration#htaccess

However, having already mod-pagespeed correctly working with Apache, it does not react to anything I put in .htaccess files. Only if I enter the same modification in the virtualhost.

The first basic thing I would like to achieve is to be able to switch mod-pagespeed on and off just by using .htaccess.
But setting

```
ModPagespeed Off
```

in .htaccess does not deactivate it.

Is there an

```
AllowOverride ModPagespeed
```

or similar I should set in the vhost.conf for this to work?

I have already tried

- AllowOverride ModPagespeed
- AllowOverride Pagespeed
- AllowOverride mod-pagespeed
- AllowOverride mod_pagespeed

But I get "Illegal override option " in all of these.

I can manipulate other apache settings successfully using .htaccess, such as mod_rewrite, htpassword, etc, so the htaccess files work.

I have no AllowOverride None, I do have a list of AllowOVerrides like this:

```
AllowOverride AuthConfig Indexes Limit
AllowOverrideList Options ErrorDocument LanguagePriority AddCharset AddEncoding AddLanguage RemoveCharset RemoveEncoding SetEnvIf SetEnvIfNoCase BrowserMatch RewriteEngine RewriteOptions RewriteBase RewriteCond RewriteRule Redirect RedirectTemp RedirectPermanent RedirectMatch
```

So I was looking for the proper way to allow overriding Pagespeed in the same way.
I have checked in other setups and it does work, indeed. But not here. 
This is using a cgi wrapper called sbox.

Any hint? Thank you.

Comment: Do you have `AllowOverride None` somewhere in your config?